How to prove for torsion free connections $A(\nabla^2 w)=0$
It's known that exterior derivative of an $n$-form $w$ can be expressed by any torsion free connection on tensor fields of a manifold as$$dw(X_0,\cdots,X_p)=\sum_i(-1)^i(\nabla_{X_i}w)(X_1,\cdots,\hat{X_i},\cdots ,X_n)$$If we define the alternating operator $A_I$ on an index set $I$ of a covariant tensor $T$ by $$A_{I}T=\sum_{\sigma\in Sym(I)}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot\sigma T$$Note if $I\subset J$ $$A_J(A_IT)=|I|!\cdot A_{J}$$
Then we can re-write $$dw=A(\nabla w)/n!$$
Now since $d^2=0$ we must have $$d^2 w=A(\nabla A(\nabla w))=AA_{(1,\cdots,n+1)}(\nabla^2 w)/n!(n+1)!=A(\nabla^2 w)/n!=0$$ So my question is

Do you have a nice (coordinate free) proof or understanding of $$A(\nabla^2 T)=0$$

When $T$ is a function this says curvature is trivial on functions, when $T$ is a 1-form this is Bianchi identity, what about $n>1$.

After some thought I believe $A(\nabla^2T)=A(RT)/2$, where $R$ is curvature form, is actually true for arbitary tensor by first Bianchi's identity. But I dont have a nice understanding about this.
